# Add class to the body when modal is open

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with my login modals. One modal open when someone click forgot password link on my sign in the modal. (One modal open in another modal) So I came everything clean by adding all necessary attributes. 
Eg:

```
  <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#forgot-pin-popup" data-dismiss="modal">Forgot password?</span>
```

But I notice it won't add **.modal-open** class to the body when my second modal is open(styles are shown weird without this class). So I manually use this js script.

```
  $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  if($('.modal').hasClass('in')) {
   $('body').addClass('modal-open');
   }    
 });
```

Works perfectly **BUT** when I try switching models like 6 times. It won't work again. Can't imagine why. I can't show you an example because it's on my production site. Does anyone face the similar problem like this?

Comment: You're missing a character in your HTML: `data-dismiss="modal"` vs `data dismiss="modal"`

Comment: Edited. It won't work even I use data-dismiss="modal"

Answer (score 2):

Try to do using modal id

On modal show

```
  $('#forgot-pin-popup').on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
    $("body").addClass("modal-open");
  });
```

On modal hide

```
  $('#forgot-pin-popup').on("hide.bs.modal", function() {
    $("body").addClass("modal-open");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

what about using a global event listeners:

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    $('body').toggleClass('modal-open', $('.modal').hasClass('in'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `body` instead of `.modal`

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  if ($('.modal.in').length) {
    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
  }
});
```

Also make sure that your modal should not be nested into `.modal` class

```js
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  if ($('.modal.in').length) {
    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
  }
});
$(".btn-primary").on("click", function() {
  console.log($("body").attr("class"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Open modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" data-dismiss="modal">
  Open modal
</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal1 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine but random times. It won't add.