# add style to body when modal is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I just want to add style to the body when my modal popup is open. After that it needs to remove when modal popup is closed. I just tried with this code. But not working at all.

```
if( $('.modal').hasClass('in') === true ) {
  $('body').style({ 'overflow': "hidden" });
  }
```

Here is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/56667/

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as what [you've already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49443614/add-class-to-the-body-when-modal-is-open)?

Answer (score 1):

modify code use for init dialog with:

```
$(elm).dialog({
   ...
   , open: function() { $("body").css({ "overflow":"hidden" }); }
   , close: function() { $("body").css({ "overflow":"" }); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the events `shown.bs.modal` and `hidden.bs.modal`. Also you are using the wrong function `style` you need to change that to `css`.

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
  $('body').css({ 'overflow': "hidden" });
}).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
  $('body').css({ 'overflow': "auto" });
});
```

```js
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
  $('body').css({ 'overflow': "hidden" });
}).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
  $('body').css({ 'overflow': "auto" });
})
```

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Open modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" data-dismiss="modal">
  Open modal
</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal1 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/56687/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap modal events. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-events

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('body').style({ 'overflow': "hidden" });
})
```

Comment: Working nicely. But need to remove when modal window closed.

Comment: This code will reset the body overflow css on the modal close. $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
  $('body').css({ 'overflow': "auto" });
});

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing CSS with JavaScript I would recommend you to use HTML classes instead:

```
var $body = $('body');

$('#myModal').on({
    'show.bs.modal': function() { $body.addClass('visible') },
    'hide.bs.modal': function() { $body.removeClass('visible') }
});
```

And CSS:

```
body {
    transition: .5s background;
}

body.visible {
    background: red;
}
```

And here is [jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/56713/).